# Why is my counter being reset each time after call toOncreate?

Tags: java, android, variables, button, increment

this is my current code

```
public class ButtonActivity extends Activity {
    int count = 0; 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                button.setText("Got Pressed:" + ++count);
                }
        });
    }
}
```

My question why after each call of onDestroy() and the subsequent call of onCreate(), the count gets reset. I looked up on onDestroy() and saw "that  is there to let your app have a final chance to clean things up before the activity does get destroyed but it does not mean that the activity will be called" My initial idea was that count is an instance variable and that onCreate() creates a new instance of my class ButtonActivity. Can anyone confirm or refute my intial thoughts ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want it reset - make it `static`: currently the counter is per object

Comment: thats what i thought. Thx So OnCreate makes a new instance of ButtonActivity? Its hard to tell if the code isnt straight up like Button Activity a = new ButtonActivity()

Answer (score 0):

Making `count` static will solve your problem. (because static member don't belong to a particular instance)

But to be more precise : `onCreate` don't create a new instance of your activity. In fact : Android-OS create a new instance and give you a chance to initialize it by calling `onCreate(...)`.

And, more generally : you can be sure that `onCreate()` will **never be called twice on the same instance**: if you see that `onCreate()` is called it's because Android-OS has just created a new instance of your Activity (it can be done for many reason, like screen rotation, ...).

More about activity lifecycle [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) (probably one of the most important concept to understand when you do Android development !)

Comment: took a lot of notes on the lifecycle, important stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

Storing static data in your activity class, as was suggested here, is a bad practice 
and should be avoided.

Why?

Because Android may destroy background activities TOGETHER with their static data 
whenever it feels resources are running low. Thus you may declare static fields inside you activity, but you will not get the static behavior you aim for,

What can you do instead:

Option 1:

Create a custom Application class and place your static data there. You will
not even have to declare it as static since Application obj is a singleton and is
guaranteed to stay in memory for as long the the app is alive.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private DataClass mydata;

    // probably with a getter & setter
}
```

Remember to declare your activity in the manifest:

```
<application
        android:name="mypackage.MyApplication"  <--------
        .....
```

Option 2: Serialize your data to [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). This is what they are for.